# How can I query bitbucket commits by date?

Tags: bitbucket

I am using this API to query commits on bitbucket repos: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/commits

It gives me some filter like `include` but I'd like to query commits based on `date`. Like `q=date>xxxx+AND+date<xxx`. How can I do that in the query?

Comment: Hi Joey, could you confirm which bitbucket hosting type you are on, Server, Data Center or Cloud? The link you provided indicates cloud, but that's not absolutely obvious.

Comment: I am using Cloud

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe this is impossible to do on cloud purely via API. Your best option will be to filter by date in your program, once you have pulled the results.

I believe this can be done on Server/DC, using the `before/after`  filters